# Erro de inserção de dados java null , Java Banco de dados Postgre

Tags: java, postgresql

Estou tentando inserir dados em uma tabela no banco, mas retorna erro "null".

```
public void cadastrarChamadas() {

    Chamadas1 cha= null;
    String sql = "Insert into tb_chamadas(cha_cod , cha_nome, cha_defeito, cha_datainicio, cha_datafinal, cha_horainicio, cha_horafinal, cha_numerovisitas, cha_tipocontrato, cha_atividadesrealizadas) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    //Capturo o valor do campoTextField e coloco em valorTextField.
    try {
        int cont=0;


        pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);

        //seta os valores
        pst.setInt(1,cha.getCod());
        pst.setString(2,cha.getNome() );
        pst.setString(3,cha.getDefeito());
        pst.setString(4,cha.getDataInicio());
        pst.setString(5, cha.getDataFinal());
        pst.setInt(6, cha.getHoraInicio());
        pst.setInt(7, cha.getHoraFinal());
        pst.setInt(8, cont+1);
        pst.setString(9, cha.getTipoServico());
        pst.setString(10, cha.getAtividadesrealiadas());



        //pst.setInt(14,Integer.parseInt(txtId.getText()));
        pst.execute();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Dados das Chamadas Salvas:");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro na Inserção de dados:\n Erro:" + e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Agora meu banco de dados.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Erro "null"? Como assim? NullPointerException, né? Se for, é por causa dessa linha: `Chamadas1 cha= null;`

Comment: Nao posso comentar ainda, entao vou escrever como se fosse resposta, tente imprimir o SQL gerado e rode ele no banco veja se funciona.
Voce pode ter errado o tipo de dados somente. Fico no aguardo.

Answer (score 1):

O objeto `cha` deve ser instanciado, recebido por parâmetro ou ser um atributo da classe que contém o método `cadastrarChamadas()`.

Deve ser algo assim:

```
public void cadastrarChamadas(Chamada1 cha) {
```

e então use o `cha` passado como parâmetro.

A linha que está lançando `NullPointerException` provavelmente é a

```
pst.setInt(1,cha.getCod());
```

Pois no seu código o `cha` está nulo, conforme a linha `Chamadas1 cha = null`.